# Writing a specific MILP problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

I would like to choose a set of $\beta_j$s that maximizes a simple linear objective function of the type

$$
\underset{\beta_j}{\operatorname{max}}\sum_{j=1}^{J}X_j\beta_j \\
$$

subject to the following constraints
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{J}C_j(\beta_j)\beta_j \le M \\
\beta_j \in \Omega \\
$$

where $X_j$ ranks the $j$s using a metric, $C_j(\beta_j)$ can be thought as a marginal cost function that changes with the chosen $\beta_j$. $\beta_j$ can only be from a set of pre-selected set of integers $\Omega$. $M$ is some budget constraint.

In addition to this, I have a hard requirement that the assigned $\beta_j$ has to be higher for a $j$ with higher $X_j$ -

$$
\beta_j > \beta_k \quad \text{when} \quad X_j>X_k
$$

what would be an elegant way of implementing this?

Comment: Can you tell us explicitly what $C_j(\beta_j)$ is? It doesn't sound likely that $C_j(\beta_j)\beta_j$ is linear, and possibly is not linearizable, and therefore not representable as a MILP.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone you are absolutely right, it is non-linear but pre-computable for all $\beta_j \in \Omega$. I solve it using the answer in https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4521/linear-objective-function-with-non-linear-constraints.

I decided to omit this detail in the question for brevity, but will edit the question if this is removing required details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple approach is to introduce a small constant tolerance $\epsilon>0$ and impose linear constraints
$$\beta_j \ge \beta_k + \epsilon \quad \text{for all $j,k$ such that $X_j > X_k$}.$$
Because $\beta_j$ and $\beta_k$ are integers, you can take $\epsilon=1$.

An alternative approach that avoids $\epsilon$ is to impose conflict constraints based on the binary variables $z_{i,j}$ introduced in the linked answer:
$$z_{i,j}+z_{\ell,k} \le 1 \quad \text{for all $i,j,k,\ell$ such that $X_j > X_k$ and $\omega_i \le \omega_\ell$}.$$

Comment: I am trying to implement the first solution and had a follow-up question. The way to implement this would be to order the data such that $X_j > X_k$ for $j = k+1$ and then set the constraint $\beta_j = \beta_k + \epsilon$ for $j=k+1$?

Comment: Yes, your suggested implementation uses $O(J)$ constraints ("transitive reduction") instead of $O(J^2)$, but make sure you have $\beta_k \ge \beta_j +\epsilon$ instead of $=$.

Comment: I am choosing this as my preferred solution as 1) it is simple and intuitive to explain to my business and also to implement and 2) this model will go into a software that needs to select the $\beta_j$ as an user changes inputs. The $\epsilon$ is a great input for the user if they want to "Create some more gaps between the $j$s".